# Apache reverse proxy for Cloud9 using ServerName

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy to a Cloud9 instance running locally on my server using Apache.  I have the following setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3131/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3131/
  ServerAdmin cloud9@mydomain.org
  ServerName cloud9.mydomain.org
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried re-ordering the directives so the ServerAdmin and ServerName came first.  So far, if I hit http://cloud9.mydomain.org, I get a browser error saying it could not connect.  There is nothing logged in Apache's access.log or error.log either.  I am thinking that I am missing some piece, but I am not sure as to what that missing piece might be yet.  I also don't know if I am looking in the right place for logs.  The Cloud9 process was started, and appears to be running on the 3131 port.

I don't plan to run Cloud9 wide open.  The end-game I am shooting for is to eventually get Cloud9 hosted through SSL using some auth, maybe basic auth, but I figured before I started adding SSL and auth into the mix, I should probably get the basics working first.

**Update**
Output of `apachectl -S`:

```
# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.mydomain.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.mydomain.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost wp.mydomain.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-wordpress:1)
         port 80 namevhost blog.mydomain.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-wordpress:22)
         port 80 namevhost cloud9.mydomain.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/003-cloud9:1)
Syntax OK
```

Output of `curl -I cloud9.mydomain.org`:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'cloud9.mydomain.org'
```

Output of `curl -I localhost:3131`:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 9
Set-Cookie: cloud9.sid.3131=bqk4zxV4ETq9rrO79E4mkJn9.YW7gMDRCsOO95utQJy1mYm8LfTfZC%2F7Fx59DeFRFDpU; path=/; expires=Thu, 19 Sep 2013 02:07:41 GMT; httpOnly
Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013 22
```

When I try to hit the site externally using Chrome, I get:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not find cloud9.mydomain.org
>
> Did you mean: mydomain.org

Which is the default page Chrome displays when it cannot connect.  Again, I don't see any errors in the access.log or error.log, unless for some reason it's not logging in the same place.  I am going into `/var/log/apache2` and doing an `ls -lart` to make sure I am seeing the latest log file.

Comment: Could you also test this from the local machine with `curl -I cloud9.mydomain.org` and let us know what you get?

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get home and will report back.

Comment: I updated the post with the requested output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<VirtualHost *.80>` - change that to `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

That might be all that's needed, but if not, can you provide the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: It was a typo.  I only had access from work using iSSH on my cellphone, so I did not have the ability to copy/past.  I corrected the original post to reflect the correct value.

Comment: @CodeChimp Ok - then can you provide the output from `apachectl -S`?  Also, what error is your client browser having - is name resolution and basic TCP connectivity to the web server working?

Comment: I updated the posting above with the requested output.

Comment: @CodeChimp The first thing you need is to add a DNS record for `cloud9.mydomain.com` - until the name resolves, you won't be able to connect to it (though you can use a hosts file locally to get past that for now and see if the rest of your configuration is working).

Comment: You gave me my "duh" moment.  Server troubleshooting 101...if you don't see any logs in your server, make sure you are actually getting to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but this works for both HTTP and SSL wo/ changes to Cloud9.

Necessary Apache module: **mod_proxy_wstunnel** (available in Apache 2.4 I think, and tutorials to build for Apache 2.2.x are available, e.g. http://www.amoss.me.uk/2013/06/apache-2-2-websocket-proxying-ubuntu-mod_proxy_wstunnel/).

```
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
RewriteRule ^(.*)smith.io(.*) /polling [P]

<Location />
   ProxyPass http://localhost:3131/
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3131/
</Location>
<Location /smith.io>
   ProxyPass ws://localhost:3131/smith.io
   ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:3131/smith.io
</Location>
<Location /polling>
   ProxyPass http://localhost:3131/smith.io/server
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3131/smith.io/server
</Location>
```